# Is there a way to see the last modified date of a file in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, last-modified

I am a new Netbeans user as well as a new Stack Overflow user.

If there is no way to see this, is there a way to see something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You must right click your file in the `Projects` tab then select `Properties` option and in the `Properties Window` you can see it in the field `Modification Time`.

[image: Screenshot]

If your file down't appear on the Projects tab try on Files tab. Files appearing on Projects tab can de both physical and logical, menwhile those ob the Files tab are strictly physical.